# Add new custom page in existing modules in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal-7

I am new on Drupal-7. I have an existing module in Drupal 7 in which I want to add a new page. Can anyone guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To add menu route you must implement hook_menu. In Drupal you make everything implementing hooks, which are simple functions. You implement a hook by replacing the string "hook" with the name of your module name inside your module file (see https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/getting-started). Ex. function mymodule_menu

In your hook_menu function you must return an associative array keyed by the path and a callback, which will return the contents of the page.

Here is the info of the menu_hook:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

I suggest, if you are a begginner in Drupal, to look the code at the Examples module. I think it's the best place to start.

https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Hope that helps.